# How to add Tax Total, Subtotal,Total and Discount Item in a Saved Search for Sales Orders record in Netsuite?

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm working with a NetSuite application and trying to create a saved search that calculates Tax Total, Subtotal,Total and Discount Item for sales orders. I've attempted to set this up in the "Results" tab of the saved search configuration, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I would appreciate any advice or examples on how to achieve this. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4BM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Formula Curreny

Tax: {taxtotal}
Shipping:
{shippingamount}

Subtotal: nvl({totalamount},0) - nvl({discountamount},0) - nvl({taxtotal},0) - nvl({shippingamount},0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).